# Как запретить сериализовать некоторые поля в JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, аннотации

Обращаюсь к контроллеру, который должен вернуть список объектов. Объекты преобразуются в JSON строку. При преобразовании объектов в JSON строку вызываются все геттеры объектов. И в результате возвращаются все данные объекта. Как запретить возврат некоторых полей объекта, может есть специальная аннотация?

```
@Controller
@MessageMapping("/v1.0")
public class MyController {

    @MessageMapping("/getList")
    @SendTo("/topic/List")
    public Collection<MyObj> getList() throws Exception {
        return this.MyObjService.getList();
    }

}
```

Собственно класс будущих объектов:

```
public class MyObj {
    private String name;
    private String login;

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
       return login;
    }

}
```

Хотелось бы запретить возврат поля `login`.

Comment: Если я угадал, то   добавление к полю аннотации  @JsonIgnore должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо! помогло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как заметил *@ArtemKonovalov* по-умолчанию Spring использует в качестве JSON Mapper-а библиотеку Jackson. Она предлагает использовать аннотацию `@JsonIgnore`.

---

## Но

рано или поздно вы захотите с одного объекта получить два разных JSON, отличающихся набором полей. Поэтому, по-хорошему нужно сделать отдельные DTO без логики, которые вы будете целиком сериализовать в JSON.

---

PS. Кроме того, рекомендую взять за правило всегда явно вешать на поля аннотацию `@JsonProperty` и явно указывать в ней имя поля. Иначе случайный  рефакторинг с переименованием поля поломает ваш API.

Comment: Спасибо! постараюсь реализовать ваш совет